# Cannot use --include when executing ng test from package.json using npm run

Tags: angular, jasmine, package.json

I am trying to run tests on a single file (my firestore rules file).  When I use the following from my command line in my project's root directory it runs fine:

```
ng test --include 'src/firestore-test/*.spec.ts'
```

I put the following in my package.json scripts section:

```
"test:rules": "ng test --include 'src/firestore-test/*.spec.ts'",
```

However, when I use "npm run test:rules" I get the following error:

*An unhandled exception occurred: Specified patterns: "'src/firestore-test/***.spec.ts'" did not match any spec files.*

Why does the command work correctly when entered into the command line but not when ran as a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick sample project with a random test in a folder of `src/firestore-test` and my results were the same as you.

I am not sure why, I am running it in PowerShell terminal but if I remove the single quotes for the `include` argument, it works.

So try this:

`"test:rules": "ng test --include src/firestore-test/*.spec.ts",`

Default Windows command prompt gave the same result as well as Bash. I am not sure how MacOS or Linux would handle it because I don't have access to them but I think removing the single quotes in the script definition should be a decent solution.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I also am using Win10 and PowerShell.  I'm surprised I hadn't seen this documented anywhere yet. Thanks!